# integration of the GitLab community version with the Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, build, gitlab

I have a GitLab and Jenkins running on the same **local machine**.I am using **community version** of the GitLab. I have configured necessary **GitLab plugins** on the Jenkins and added **GitLab API token** as well but still I am getting authorization problem while accessing GitLab from Jenkins.

While searching for solution I read that only GitLab Enterprise version integration is possible with the Jenkins? Is it true?

I tried integration of Jenkins with the repository created on **https://gitlab.com** and it's working properly.

Can any one help me understand what causing the above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate GitLab CE (community Edition) and Jenkins.
I am using the [GitLab Hook Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin)

You must have a jenkins deploy key that is activated on the GitLab projects that Jenkins has to access.
Check if you have the same at `https://yourgitlab/admin/deploy_keys`.

Comment: Okay. I am following the same document provided by you.

Comment: @Abhinandan we have a jenkins deploy key that we activate on the projects Jenkins has to access. Check if you have the same at https://yourGitLab/admin/deploy_keys

Comment: No.I don't have that key.I will create one and then try.

Comment: I have successfully  integrated the git-lab with the Jenkins.The problem was that gitlab project was private and that's why I was not able to access it using the access token.I have accessed it by setting up the SSH key pair. I referred  the instractions from here - https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738
.Though it is for git-hub the procedure is pretty much same.